# Parent/Child Design For a Basic Social Network Using SQL

Tags: sql, oop, foreign-keys, relationship, social-networking

I'm trying to build a simple structure for a social network style application. But I have a little confusion about how to design the relationship between `posts`, `comments` and `medias`.
So simply, `media` can be an `image` or a `video` (with enumaration). It contains `size` and `URL` info about a standard image, thumbnail and video (according to the `mediaType` enumaration). A `post` may have multiple `media` attached to it. A `comment` may have multiple `media` attached to it. But when a `media` is used at one place, it cannot be used at another. No other `post` can have it. No other `comment` can have it. Also, when I implement `users`, they can refer to an image type `media` as their profilePic. When there will be a `messaging` feature, some `media` might be attached to a `message` etc. So, I want things to be a little flexible.

I didn't want to add specific columns about about `thumbnailWidth`, `thumbnailSize`, `thumbnailURL` etc to multiple tables, because it would be just too much repetation. So I've decided to use a centralized `media` table to hold all the main information about an uploaded image or video.
I've decided to put the thumbnail and standard image infos to the same row, otherwise it just felt too complicated to handle. I may divide `images` and `videos` to separate tables later.

Note: I don't have a structure for comments to reply each other. That is a later concern :)

Here is the current design without the connection between `media` and other tables.

```
Media
----------
id
thumbnail_width
thumbnail_height
thumbnail_URL
standard_width
standard_height
standard_URL
media_type ("video" or "image")
source_URL (only used if media_type is "video")
(maybe other columns to be used with "video" type)
user_id (who uploaded the media)

Post
----------
id
title
body
user_id (who sent the post.)

Comment
----------
id
body
post_id (which post has this comment)
user_id
```

**Option 1**
So one option is, putting `commentId` and  `postId` fields (as nullable) to `media` table.
If a media is attached to a post, put the postId there. If it is attached to a comment, do same for  the `commentId`. If one of them has a value, others must be `null`. But this may result in too many reference columns in the `media` table, because a `media` might be used in a lot of places as the project grows.

**Option2**
Another option is creating tables for each relationship like;

```
PostMedia
----------
id
post_id
media_id (unique. one-to-one relationship with Media table)

CommentMedia
----------
id
comment_id
media_id (unique. one-to-one relationship with Media table)
```

But now it becomes harder to check if a media is used in a `post`, before saving a `comment`. Or the other way around. We need to check the whole `PostMedia` table each time.

Another situation might be, when a user sets a `media` with the `image` type as their profile picture, we need to check if it was used in a post or a comment. I'm not sure about this constraint but it might come in handy for some situations.

I might set some `ownerType` enumaration in `media` table. That might be `post`, `comment`, `profilePic` etc. And `PostMedia` table could reference a media only if the `ownerType` is `post`.

**Option 3**
The centralized `Media` table idea is cool, but it comes with a lot of complexity I think. With an object-oriented design, I might just create an abstract `media` class, put all of the required columns and methods in that class and extend it as `PostMedia`, `CommentMedia` etc. And it would be much more easy to handle, but ends up a lot of same columns and similar tables across the db. I don't know if it is a good design.

What would be the best practice here? I might be thinking things too complicated, there might be simpler solutions. I'm open to any advices :)

Thanks!

Comment: Are you familiar with Entity Relation Models and the normalisation process?

Comment: I use ER Models time to time, if I need to visualize a little bit confusing or complicated schemas. I'm not sure about the "normalisation process". Even if I've used it, I may not know the name of it :)

Comment: *"What would be the best practice here?"* Write down all the known functional dependencies, and generate the database schema from them. All the normal forms through BCNF are determined by their functional dependencies.